# how to download a folder from bash?

Tags: download, directory

I want to download a complete folder from a jenkins project containing many folder

I try with a wget and it works for only one file doing :

```
wget http://jenkinsmedia:XXXX/job/Lib//280/artifact/tool.rpm
```

but in the same place there is tool.rpm, there is a folder Test

I want to download the whole folder, is it possible? Or will I have to pick files one by one?

Comment: Try: `wget -r http://jenkinsmedia:XXXX/job/Lib//280/artifact/`

Comment: thx but do I have to set it alone? it says it doesn't exist... but might just be absent from my linux version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `wget -r http://jenkinsmedia:XXXX/job/Lib//280/artifact/`

This will create a folder, in that folder it will have a folder `job` and so on..

use `wget -nH --cut-dirs=4 -r http://jenkinsmedia:XXXX/job/Lib//280/artifact/` if you just want to have the folder with the documents

Comment: thanks a lot! Where I work we have a Yocto, and I believe this command is not set in our working system. would there be another command to do it? because it doesn't recognise -r

Comment: here is the error I get
wget: invalid option -- 'r'
BusyBox v1.22.1 (2015-04-28 16:00:12 EDT) multi-call binary.

Usage: wget [-c|--continue] [-s|--spider] [-q|--quiet] [-O|--output-document FILE]
        [--header 'header: value'] [-Y|--proxy on/off] [-P DIR]
        [-U|--user-agent AGENT] [-T SEC] URL...

Comment: Yocto is just a linux but with reduced number of commands (used by companies) so this means I don't have access to -r command... are there any other possibilities or would I need to move file by file?

Comment: I see... thx for the help, I'll mark it as an answer trusting it works ;)